# Laravel Mix Custom Produce Big JS File

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm having trouble caused by the big size file of bundle that is created via webpack

It produce the bundle around 1.38mb which slowing down the web on the first load

I'm using laravel mix webpack for react preset

I have already try to give some plugin on the webpack to reduce the size but it seems doesn't work at all

Before giving the plugin it produce 1.38mb file, after giving the plugin it still 1.38mb file

here are the plugins i'm using

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // <-- key to reducing React's size
            'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), //dedupe similar code 
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        output: {
            comments: false
        },
        mangle: true,
        sourcemap: false,
        debug: false,
        minimize: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false,
            screw_ie8: true,
            conditionals: true,
            unused: true,
            comparisons: true,
            sequences: true,
            dead_code: true,
            evaluate: true,
            if_return: true,
            join_vars: true
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()//Merge chunks
```

anyone has suggestion for my problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you geting this file after

> npm run dev 
>   Or 
>   npm run prod 
>   If you are using npm run prod I think its bigg and you need to try compile your react app using create react app if not try to use npm run prod

this is create react app webpack config file

```
    'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
const publicPath = paths.servedPath;
// Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
// For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
const publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1);
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Assert this just to be safe.
// Development builds of React are slow and not intended for production.
if (env.stringified['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
  throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

// Note: defined here because it will be used more than once.
const cssFilename = 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css';

// ExtractTextPlugin expects the build output to be flat.
// (See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/27)
// However, our output is structured with css, js and media folders.
// To have this structure working with relative paths, we have to use custom options.
const extractTextPluginOptions = shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths
  ? // Making sure that the publicPath goes back to to build folder.
    { publicPath: Array(cssFilename.split('/').length).join('../') }
  : {};

// This is the production configuration.
// It compiles slowly and is focused on producing a fast and minimal bundle.
// The development configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: true,
  // We generate sourcemaps in production. This is slow but gives good results.
  // You can exclude the *.map files from the build during deployment.
  devtool: shouldUseSourceMap ? 'source-map' : false,
  // In production, we only want to load the polyfills and the app code.
  entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path
        .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
        .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {

      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works just like "file" loader but it also embeds
          // assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {

              compact: true,
            },
          },
          // The notation here is somewhat confusing.
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader normally turns CSS into JS modules injecting <style>,
          // but unlike in development configuration, we do something different.
          // `ExtractTextPlugin` first applies the "postcss" and "css" loaders
          // (second argument), then grabs the result CSS and puts it into a
          // separate file in our build process. This way we actually ship
          // a single CSS file in production instead of JS code injecting <style>
          // tags. If you use code splitting, however, any async bundles will still
          // use the "style" loader inside the async code so CSS from them won't be
          // in the main CSS file.
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              Object.assign(
                {
                  fallback: {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    options: {
                      hmr: false,
                    },
                  },
                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                      options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                      options: {
                        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: () => [
                          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                          autoprefixer({
                            browsers: [
                              '>1%',
                              'last 4 versions',
                              'Firefox ESR',
                              'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                            ],
                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                          }),
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                extractTextPluginOptions
              )
            ),
            // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure assets end up in the `build` folder.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its filename.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // it's runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
          // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
    // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV was set to production here.
    // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // Minify the code.
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
        // Pending further investigation:
        // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
        comparisons: false,
      },
      mangle: {
        safari10: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2488
        ascii_only: true,
      },
      sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
    }),
    // Note: this won't work without ExtractTextPlugin.extract(..) in `loaders`.
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: cssFilename,
    }),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    }),
    // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
    // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
      // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
      // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
      // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
      dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      logger(message) {
        if (message.indexOf('Total precache size is') === 0) {
          // This message occurs for every build and is a bit too noisy.
          return;
        }
        if (message.indexOf('Skipping static resource') === 0) {
          // This message obscures real errors so we ignore it.
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2612
          return;
        }
        console.log(message);
      },
      minify: true,
      // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
      navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
      // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
      // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
      staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
    }),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
};
```

Comment: I am using npm run production which produce app.js minified. How can i recompile the js using create react app?

Comment: I had the same problem in the past and I moved my front end part t create-react-app to solve that you can try it or copy the production webpack config from it.

Comment: So you just copying all your react component to the create react app project? Have you tried to copy the webpack config?

Comment: no I copy all the react project to create react app and complete working with using create react app and when the project done I just put the compiled app.js to laravel project because in react create app you can control your project and see all unused components, functions, variables.. and remove them